# Mysql getting relational results from different tables depending on value

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I suppose this is less of a technical question and more of a logical one. The company I am developing a system for offers memberships, both for groups and individuals. I'm having a bit of trouble deciding on the db architecture. For starters, I've got two tables; one for `individual contacts` and one for `group contacts`.

- `tbl_contact_individual`
- `tbl_contact_group`

**edit** - these tables have different schemas from each other (individual has `first_name` `last_name`, group has `parent_group_id` `primary_contact_id`, etc) so they can't be combined.

I could store all the members in one `member` table and use php to decide which table to pull the contact info from based off of the membership level, however this results in a non-specific `contact_id` column that: a) could refer to one of two different tables and b) contain duplicate values (even though they refer to different db entries). This seems kinda hacky. So this is what I'm thinking instead.

- `tbl_member_individual`
- `tbl_member_group`
- `view_member`

As you might assume, I would have separate tables for group and individual members with a view merging the two for easy listing. Other tables need to refer to the member entries, if that makes a difference at all. This seems simple enough but I can't help but feel like I'm overlooking something.

Or am I over complicating things? Should I just have a `group_id` column and an `individual_id` column in a central `member` table and leave one null depending on the membership type?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your individual and group contact tables have a different schema? If not, you can just use a flag column. Eg a column for "name", "address", "city", etc, as well as a "contact_type" column with a value of either "I" or "C".

Comment: yes they do. Sorry, should have mentioned that. I'll update my question

Comment: "_Or am I over complicating things? Should I just have a group_id column and an individual_id column in a central member table and leave one null depending on the membership type?_" You already have the best answer ;-)

Comment: Great, thanks! I have a bad tendency to overthink this sorts of scenarios and occasionally end up building something far more complex than necessary :)

Comment: Sorry to disapoint you, but after your edit, I must rethink too :-)

Comment: Have a look at [class-table-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/class-table-inheritance/info)

Comment: Option 1: Each of contact tables should anyway have a PK column with an identical name like `id`. Then, in your member table create a column `contact_id`. Insert an "individual" entity in `member` table and write it's corresponding `id` value in the column `contact_id` of `member`. Insert a "group" entity in `member` table and write it's corresponding `id` value in the column "contact_id" of `member`. Option 2: Your solution from last phrase as earlier commented. It depends further also on what relationship individual and group have (if any).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel has suggested the best applicable option, indeed what you should exactly be doing in a situation like this. Remember your Groups or Individuals are still `MEMBERS`, and as `MEMBERS` they probably have common attributed which it makes no sense to save in 2 tables with same column names and same type of data. It would also be a lot more convenient to get membership analytics if you had  a `MEMBER` class/table with `INDIVIDUAL` and `GROUP` sub classes/tables.

Comment: @aendeeri - Thank you so much! I'm feeling like I've got a better grasp on this now.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Thank you as well. I figured this had to be a pretty common scenario with a fairly standardized solution but I had no clue what to google to get the right answer! :)